# On the diophantine equation $x^5+y^5=z^5+t^5$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

It is known that the diophantine equation $x^5+y^5=z^5+t^5$,
has infinity many trivial solutions.
Has this equation been proven to have other integer solutions?

Comment: Such numbers are called taxibac numbers , for exponent $5$ or more , no such taxicab number is known.

Comment: euh , NO , no solutions are known apart from $x=z,y=t$.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation5thPowers.html

Comment: @mick The case $p=5$ is solvable by Gaussian integers, in reference to [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4821037/4781) on $p=11$ and Eisenstein integers.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I am somewhat aware of that. I do not know the parametrization of all solutions if there is one. But I know there are solutions. Not so surprising since solutions for $p=5$ might even have ordinary integer solutions( that is an open problem) and many arguments exist for it, and those arguments get stronger for a bigger ring ofc.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII It would be nice if you had a link to all those solutions though :)
Ofcourse you have the answer you give, what is nice, but I assume more are known ?

Comment: @mick Yes, for $p=5$, more is known and solving it in Gaussian integers is just a special case. The degree is low enough that it can be solved by methods similar to $p=3$, and a variety of quadratic integers, but it seems _just_ out of reach of the ordinary integers. Yes, it is an open problem, but I'm more inclined to believe the LPS conjecture.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII LPS is for ordinary integers only as I recall ?

Answer (score 4):

**I.** The OP asks for "*...other integer solutions*". We will interpret this to allow for [*Gaussian integers*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianInteger.html) $a+bi$, an important class of *quadratic integers*. Hence, a non-trivial solution is,

$$(a+ci)^5+(b-ci)^5 = (a-ci)^5+(b+ci)^5$$

where $a^2+b^2 = 2c^2,\,$ and $a\neq b.\,$ A version was first found by Desboves. For example, $(a,b,c) = (1,7,5)$, so,

$$(1+5i)^5+(7-5i)^5 = (1-5i)^5+(7+5i)^5$$

and infinitely more.

---

**II.** However, if the OP wishes for plain vanilla integers, then no non-trivial solutions are known to,

$$a^5+b^5 = c^5+d^5 = N$$

where $N < 1.02\times10^{26}$ (Guy, 1994) cited in Mathworld. However, this has been updated to $N < 4.01\times10^{30}$ ([Ekl, 1998](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1998-67-223/S0025-5718-98-00979-X/S0025-5718-98-00979-X.pdf)). This roughly implies there are no solutions with both $(a,b)<10^6.$

**P.S.** Ekl's 25-year-old bound seems to need an update, though the *Lander-Parkin-Selfridge conjecture* assumes there are none anyway.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lander,_Parkin,_and_Selfridge_conjecture

Comment: In what year did Desboves find that ?

Comment: @mick Adolphe Desboves lived during the 1800s, so it was within that time.

Comment: yes I was aware of the century but not the exact date of that result. Thanks anyway.