# The diophantine $a^{11} + b^{11} = c^{11} + d^{11} = s$ for Eisenstein integers.

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,c,d,s$ be distinct nonzero Eisenstein integers.

Claim :
$$a^{11} + b^{11} = c^{11} + d^{11} = s$$

has only a finite number of solutions for any given $s$.

In fact at most $22$ for any $s$.

Is this true ? Is it known or studied ?

Any references ?

Comment: Where did you get the number 22 from? What source

Comment: @ArielFishbein oh $2*11$ , where $11$ approximates 11th roots of unity but scaled ( multiplied by large real )  and approximated by Eisenstein integers. And $2$ the ways to arrange the sum.  That is not formal ofcourse.  Good question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer

Comment: So we fix an integer $s$ in the cyclotomic field $\Bbb Q(\omega)$, $\omega$ being a primitive third root of the unit. And ask for the solutions $(a,b)$ of $a^{11}+b^{11}=s$. (We may add $a\ne b$.) The question is only about the number of the solutions $(a,b)$ (finitely many), or we need also $(c,d)$ and that $22$ is part of the question?

Comment: @dan_fulea if we do not need the $(c,d)$ the question is different , we just add $a^{11}$ and $b^{11}$ and get a solution. But that is not the diophantine with $a,b,c,d$. So we DO NEED the c and d

Comment: I thought $s$ is given, fixed. And for such an $s$ we are searching for pairs $(a,b)$, identified with $(b,a)$, realizing $s$ as $a^{11}+b^{11}$. The question is thus to find numbers $s$ which can be realized in at least two different ways, and it is a question about the finiteness of the set of these $s$-values?

Comment: Are we counting $(a,b)$ pairs such that $a^{11}+b^{11}=s$? Or quads $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $a^{11}+b^{11}=c^{11}+d^{11}=s$? Can you give an example of $s$ such that there are 22 solutions?

Comment: With $s=0$ we trivially have infinitely many solutions from $b=-a$, but that's not very interesting :-)

Comment: @dan_fulea I myself am uncertain what the OP wants. But there is only one known solution which I gave in my answer, though I had to go beyond Eisenstein integers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen There is only one known solution (not in Eisenstein integers), and I am not sure how he can extract 22 solutions from it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen we are counting quads. But the difference between those quads and pairs is almost identical. If we can write it as a pair in 3 ways then by simple combinatorics we can write it as quads in 3 ways.

Comment: If no case of 22 solutions, then what kind of example data have you available, Mick?

Comment: FWIW All the repetitions among the numbers $a^{11}+b^{11}$ with $a,b$ non-zero Eisenstein's integers  drawn from the set $J=\{m+n\omega\mid |m|,|n|\le6\}$ have either $b=-a$ or just intechange $a$ and $b$. In other words, no non-trivial repetitions in $J$. I included the solutions of the form $a=0, b=-z, c=\omega z, d=z\omega^2$ among the trivial ones (see my comment under Tito's answer). I guess I could easily extend the range, but I'm sure we have other users who are more capable programmers :-)

Comment: I made a small edit. Thanks guys.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have no nontrivial solutions. I am not even sure nontrivial solutions exist. I guess it is only like up to unit multiples and such.

Answer (score 4):

The equation,

$$a^{11}+b^{11} = c^{11}+d^{11}\tag1$$

is difficult to solve using quadratic integers, especially if we limit ourselves to *Eisenstein integers*. So we generalize things slightly and consider the ring of quadratic integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ that is *both* a "principal ideal domain" *and* "Euclidean domain". Then for negative discriminants $D$  we only have *five*:

$$D = (-1,\,-2,\,-3,\,-7,\,-11)$$

and, voila, we have the single known identity for $11$th powers,

$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}2\right)^{11}+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{-7}}2\right)^{11}=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-11}}2\right)^{11}+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{-11}}2\right)^{11}= 67$$

given in [this 2017 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097142/does-sqrtp-sqrtq11-sqrtp-sqrtq11-sqrtr-sqrts11). I don't know of any other solution for $(1)$ using quadratic integers, nor if,

$$a^{13}+b^{13} = c^{13}+d^{13}\tag2$$

is also solvable, but is probably not.

Comment: +1 though those are 2 distinct rings and not Eisenstein.

Comment: @mick Yes. I've looked at this problem before. As it is of high degree, it may need _two_ Euclidean domains, and not necessarily Eisenstein. Though I just realized that $$\big(2+\sqrt{-3}\big)^{11}+\big(2-\sqrt{-3}\big)^{11} = 2^2\cdot67$$ so the prime $p=67$ seems to be well-represented.

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding your statement, but I think there is no shortage of solutions in $\mathcal{O}=\Bbb{Z}[\omega],\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$. If $z\in\mathcal{O}$ is any Eisensteinian integer we have trivially
$$z^{11}+(\omega z)^{11}+(\omega^2z)^{11}=0.$$ Yielding solutions of the type $a=0, b=-z, c=\omega z, d=\omega^2z$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see. I guess we should specify that $a\neq0$. Otherwise, we have $$z^k+(\omega z)^k+ (\omega^2 z)^k = 0$$ for any odd exponent $k\neq3m$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII you seem to like number theory. 
Im not sure if it is ok to ask like this but, maybe this is something you can answer : 
Or maybe even correct or improve if needed.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815649/prime-twin-counting-by-pi-2t2-sum-2jt2-2-omegaj-1-2-lf

Comment: @Tito Piezas III, For degree 13 if we consider the simillar form as in degree 11, (1+p)^13+(1-p)^13=(1+q)^13+(1-q)^13, then we have the equation, [(m^6-n^6)+22(m^5-n^5)+99(m^4-n^4)+132(m^3-n^3)+55(m^2-n^2)+6(m-n)]=0. where (m,n)=(p^2,q^2). Hence we need to solve a sixth degree equation (in disquise) for for imaginary numbers.